# Unexpected result for a list item

Tags: parsing, python-3.x

Running this:

```python
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
count = 0
open(fname)
for line in fname:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('From:') : continue
    if line.startswith('From '): 
        count = count + 1
        words = line.split()
        print words[1]
```

(through Mac terminal with python 3.x)

I get:

```
Enter file name:romeo.txt
['\x00J\x00u\x00l\x00i\x00e\x00t\x00', '\x00a\x00l\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00d\x00y\x00', '\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00', '\x00b\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00k\x00s\x00)', '\x00e\x00a\x00s\x00t\x00', '\x00e\x00n\x00v\x00i\x00o\x00u\x00s\x00', '\x00f\x00a\x00i\x00r\x00', '\x00g\x00r\x00i\x00e\x00f\x00', '\x00i\x00s\x00', '\x00k\x00i\x00l\x00l\x00', '\x00l\x00i\x00g\x00h\x00t\x00', '\x00m\x00o\x00o\x00n\x00)', '\x00p\x00a\x00l\x00e\x00', '\x00s\x00i\x00c\x00k\x00', '\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00', '\x00s\x00u\x00n\x00', '\x00s\x00u\x00n\x00)', '\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00', '\x00t\x00h\x00r\x00o\x00u\x00g\x00h\x00', '\x00w\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00', '\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00o\x00w\x00', '\x00w\x00i\x00t\x00h\x00', '\x00y\x00o\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00r\x00', 'A\x00r\x00i\x00s\x00e\x00', 'I\x00t\x00', 'W\x00h\x00o\x00', '\xff\xfeB\x00u\x00t\x00']
```

I'll figure out the exercise, but I don't recognize or understand this result or why it's happening.

Comment: It looks like a UTF-16 file. Try opening using `open(fname, encoding='UTF-16')`.

Comment: You're not iterating over the contents of the file, you're iterating over the contents of `fname`... (using `open(fname)` doesn't magically make `fname` use the file...) and you second `if` will never execute as the preceding `if` that shares the same criteria immediately continues anyway... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to count the lines that start with 'From ' and not with 'From: " and split the words of the 'From ' line? Or are you just trying to learn how to open a file?